# Record audio with Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, audio

How can I record audio on Windows Phone 8.1 without installing any third part app? 
I have a Nokia Lumia 920 with WP 8.1.

Comment: Record a video and extract the audio later?

Comment: is there a function to extract the audio? Anyway this is not an acceptable solution, why would I want to waste memory and time for nothing?

Comment: I don't believe there's a built-in way to extract the audio, you'd have to do it on a PC. If you have additional criteria (e.g. the audio has to be ready to use on the phone), then you should add them to your question.

Comment: or you can use the camera to make a video, and any audio will also be recorded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can record sound inside the preinstalled OneNote app. If you need to you can sync the recording to your PC using the OneNote desktop application and save it there (right click -> save as...).

Windows 10 for phones will actually [include a dedicated sound recording app](http://www.windowscentral.com/sound-recorder-app-windows-10-phones-minimal-effective).

Comment: Nice, I'd forgotten about OneNote's audio recording feature!

Comment: @Thomas, do you know where an audio file produced with OneNote is saved? Is there a way to open it other than with OneNote? Thanks

Comment: it is saved within the OneNote notebook so unfortunately there's no way to extract it without the software.