# Where is my audio taken from OneNote saved?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, audio, onenote

I got that I can record an audio file with OneNote app.

I am wondering where it is saved once I recorded it and eventually how I can pick it.

I have a lumia 920 with wp8.1.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9317/how-to-record-audio-with-windows-phone-8-1-and-nokia-lumia-920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recordig is being saved within your OneNote document so there's no way to access it through the file explorer (neither on the phone nor when conencting it to the pc).

When your document is synced to the cloud you can either download your audio file by opening the web-version of [OneNote](https://www.onenote.com/) or by extracting it through the desktop version (for both right-click => save as...).

Comment: On the desktop version, when you right click and 'save as', it is saved in the `WMA` format