# Is there a way to record audio in the background or even when the screen is locked?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, audio, audio-recording

I needed to record audio while I was on the go. I tried some Apps from the Store, but I couldn't find any that was able to record *while* the screen was **locked**.

I can't walk with my phone in my hand and I have to lock it before putting it back in my pocket in order to prevent accidental actions on the screen.

Also, I couldn't find an App that can record *while* it's in background.

In [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/9318/9313) I read that Windows 10 mobile will include a minimal App to record audio, I tried to search online for more information, but I can't find any details about the ability to record in background or with the screen **locked**.

Comment: I can confirm that the Windows 10 Voice Recorder pauses recording when the screen is locked. This would be something I'd be interested in looking into doing, though, as a dev.

Comment: @shawn thank you for the input. Please, convert your comment into an answer, as you answered what I wanted to know (so that I can assign you the bounty). And if you'll develop an App for background recording (I don't know if Windows 10 mobile APIs will allow that) please let me know by updating this question! Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is one. I too faced the same problem and at last I got one.
Go on the store and look for [Mini Recorder Free](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/mini-recorder-free/9wzdncrfj22p).

It works for me and I do love this app.

Comment: wow thank you! I tried a bunch of apps then I just gave up since any of them record with the screen locked. The one you suggested records *while* the screen is locked, it does not while it is in background, but it is already better than any others I tried!

Comment: Yes, it dont work in background but for the matter of screen is locked it is better and you can see the sound quality. Amazing!

Comment: @Manuel Mini Recorder got one more property :) Yesterday I was listening FM Radio. Just ried to record songs through it and guess what!  It did but only if I play through loudspeakers not headset!

Answer (score 2):

The Voice Recorder app in Windows 10 Mobile does not allow recording while the phone is locked. It pauses the recording. Currently I don't know of any apps that will allow you to do this, though I will try to look into the API's and see if it's possible, and update this answer to include that.

Comment: I'm looking forward to know if it is possible to develop such an App. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Perfect Recorder](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh16n0b) app is doing the job perfectly and it's for FREE.
It's still annoying that Microsoft can't make a recorder which can work when the screen is locked.

Answer (score 0):

This two apps will record voice in background

1. [Pocket Recorder](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/pocket-recorder/eda4e045-733f-e011-854c-00237de2db9e)
2. [Voice Recorder 8.1](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/voice-recorder-8-1/511c6375-8bf3-4d19-8248-1650a60ea1ae)

Comment: None of them either records in the background or when the screen is locked...

Answer (score 0):

A new Windows 10 app called WhatUHear will record loopback (from speakers)
Works in background and locked. An update is due this week to include microphone too. Phone and PC.

[WhatUHear UWP](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9p0tj0xszw15)